# How to use rowTemplate and detailTemplate together in KendoUI?

Tags: kendo-ui

I having trouble using a rowtemplate with a detail grid.

Basically when I use them in combination, the rendering is messed up.

See this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yzKqV/,  to reproduce this error (uncomment the commented out line and run again to see the error).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the reason your rowTemplate is not working when you use detailTemplate is because it needs to have the tr and first td defined like a hierarchy grid. (http://jsfiddle.net/yzKqV/3/)

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr class="k-master-row"> 
        <td class="k-hierarchy-cell"><a href="\#" class="k-icon k-plus"></a></td>
        <td> #= FirstName # </td>
        <td> #= LastName # </td> 
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Daniel, i want the detail template to show inline like its meant to be (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html)

As you can see from my original fiddle, the rendering is messed up if both are included

Comment: I updated my answer to have the detail template shown inline.

Comment: Supersaver! Thanks for this post.